# How to send command through serial same way it does with PuTTy in a python script

Tags: serial-port, pyserial

I have a HPLC pump connected via serial port to the computer. By using PuTTy I can send commands to it such as REMOTE to control it from PC (the display will change on the pump to show that it is indeed in remote mode. However when I use the same command from python the device does not respond.

```
import serial
pump = serial.Serial(port='COM2', baudrate=19200)
```

I have tried

```
pump.write('REMOTE\n'.encode())
```

and

```
pump.write(b'REMOTE\n')
```

and

```
pump.write(b'REMOTE')
```

Comment: Some of your settings are probably wrong, can you include a link to the manual of the pump? or, you can add a screenshot of the configuration you are using successfully with PuTTY

Comment: This is what the Pump Manual says
Communication protocol settings
The following settings are used for the RS232 communication port:
Baud rate: 115200; 38400, 19200, 9600 Stop bits: 1 Data bits: 8 Parity: None Flow control: hardware

The PuTTy settings are 
COM2
19200 baud
8 Data Bits
1 Stop bit
no parity
xonxoff flow control

Comment: Are you sure about those? Flow control sounds funny, it should be the same on both sides, be it PuTTY, Pyserial or your hardware. It should be either XON/XOFF or hardware, not both. Anyway, you can try `pump.xonxoff=True`, `pump.rtscts=True` or `pump.dsrdtr=True`

Comment: I also found that odd. I left PuTTY mostly default besides the baudrate, and had it working, with the xonxoff. 
Had not got around to looking at the manual's configuration until now.

In the pyhton shell xonxoff and rtscts both run and there is no response on the pump. The dsrdtr however gets stuck and hangs with a blinking cursor, and no response on the pump.

Comment: dsrdtr hangs in PuTTY too, rtscts works though. So both xonxoff and rtscts work in PuTTY.

Comment: Are you using the same serial port with the same cable for PuTTY and Python? what you say sounds very odd indeed.

Comment: By the way, hardware flow control (RTS-CTS or DSR-DTR) is completely different than [XON/XOFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568733/what-does-xon-xoff-flow-control-actually-do). Hardware flow control requires you to connect more cables than just TX, RX and GND. But based on what you say I'm guessing your device works with XON/XOFF and does not need hardware flow control. Some versions of Pyserial had issues with XON/XOFF, so you might want to update or make sure your version is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

I needed to use

```
pump.write(b'REMOTE\r')
```

not

```
\n
```